# Groovy Script Performance Contains vs Matches

Tags: java, groovy

I am new to groovy language. I am using groovy code to check the response from the http url if it is valid. From performance perspective, what is typically advisable to use - contains() or matches() which would allow me to validate if I got correct response.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, you're making an http request, and this will be the majority of the time taken by whatever you're doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java `contains()` or `in` operator of Groovy checks for exact match on plain string basis and basically is a shortcut for `-1 != str.indexOf('aaa')`.

On the other hand, `matches()` in java or `==~` and `=~` in groovy introduce Regex Patter matching overhead and are somewhat slower. This is the price you are paying for power and flexibility of regex.

Going back to your use case, I think the performance cost of `matches()` over `contains()` is negclectible, as the http request takes magnitudes of time longer to execute.

In this case I would go for solution with greater readability and flexibility, which would be a regex way. On the other hand, if you really want exact match, you should stick with `contains`.

Beyond the abovementioned, if you really want the last drop of performance, you should run the load tests of both methods yourself.